# Are variable length arrays supported under std=gnu89?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c89, variable-length-array

My code contains the following line:

```
int counts[config.max_c];
```

I was surprised to see that it compiled without issue using default `gcc` without any flags. According to `man gcc` the default standard for c code is `gnu89`. Does this standard support this type of array initialisation, and if so where can I find a reference?

Comment: Quote from the man pages: "gnu89 -
GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is the default for C code." with some c99 features, vlas are included(as stated in the [man pages](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) of vlas. sadly, you will have to look up every feature you are interested in and see if it is supported.

Comment: Just to add to +Carson's comment, to clear things up, `gnu89` (which us an alias for `gnu90`) isn't considered a _standard_, just a _'dialect'_, which is why the answers are as they are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this standard support this type of array initialisation, and if so where can I find a reference?

No. It doesn't support variable length arrays.

Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, **and as an [extension GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)**.
Although you are compiling your code in C89, it compiles without error because of the GCC extension.

Answer (score 1):

[gcc's default dialect to use is C90.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)

[For C90 gcc supports VLAs as an extension.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: GCC's default (apparently only up until recent versions, where they finally made the switch to `gnu11` by default, though I don't think I've used these versions yet) is to use the `gnu90` (`gnu89` is exactly the same) dialect for C code, which means, at least under GCC, that it will be supported by default (via the extensions). I think it is supported even with `-std=c90` (same as `c89`), since that only turns off certain extensions (same result as `-ansi`) unless you use `-pedantic`, but don't quote me on that.